# React Native + Jest - Trying to test async UDP method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, node-modules

Hey guys I have this method with uses dgram or more specifically react-native-udp library for working with udp protocol.

```
import * as dgram from 'react-native-udp' //dgram only works for react web

export const onMessage = (handleDiscovery: any): any => {
    const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
    socket.bind(3001)
    socket.on('message', function (msg, rinfo) {
        handleDiscovery(msg, rinfo)
    })
}
```

When I try to test it with Jest:

```
it('ASYNC', () => {
    udp.onMessage((msg, rinfo) => {
        console.log(msg, rinfo)
        expect(1).toBe(1)
    })
})
```

I get this error:

```
Reducers must work correctly › ASYNC
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSocket' of undefined
```

The weird part is that the code works correctly in android device, but not on test suite. Do I have to reimport it for testing?

Comment: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-udp) it's imported as `require('dgram')`

Comment: @vasekhlav yeah but for react native we have to use 'react-native-udp'

Comment: did you take a look at their [example app](https://github.com/tradle/react-native-udp/blob/master/examples/rctsockets/index.ios.js)?

Comment: can you show all your code from your `test`